# Limit of increasing sequence of nonpositive harmonic/subharmonic functions

Tags: functional-analysis

I have two True/False questions I have not been able to figure out:

a) The limit of an increasing sequence of nonpositive harmonic functions on the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is harmonic.

b) The limit of an increasing sequence of nonpositive continuous subharmonic functions on the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is continuous subharmonic.

Comment: Consider the respective mean value properties of harmonic and subharmonic functions.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Fischer has pointed out in the comments, you can use the mean (or sub-mean) value properties of harmonic and subharmonic functions on the ball to prove that the limit function would be harmonic in (a) and subharmonic in (b). Thus the statement in (a) is true, and is proved in many texts on potential theory.

However, in (b) I believe there is a problem, in that the resulting limit of an increasing sequence of non-positive continuous subharmonic functions need not be continuous.

Consider the functions $f_n(x) = \displaystyle{\frac{-1}{n\|x\|}}$. For each $n$, we know that $f_n$ is harmonic on $B(0,1)\setminus \{0\}$, and hence the function $g_n(x) = \max(-1,f_n(x))$ is subharmonic on the whole of the unit ball. However, the limit of the sequence $\{g_n\}$ is the function which is zero throughout the unit ball, except for at the origin, where it is $-1$. Hence the limit is not continuous and the statement in (b) is false.